# piecewise signal function

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I have to construct an input signal to do integration and some operation on it on MATLAB,
this is my code, how to get rid of impulse shape?

```
syms t
x(t)=piecewise(0<t<2,-3,2<t<3,7*t+14,3<t<4,-3*t+12,4<t<5,0);
fplot(x)
```

[image: d]

Comment: The `piecewise` function you defined determines the shape of the graph. If you don't want that shape, you need to define it differently.

Comment: yes I got your point I will try now, I did not have any idea how to get rid of it

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/301846/velvel How to change it to the required shape as shown?

Comment: @Velvel how to change it to the required shape?

Comment: @Manar Uni - The pulse shape shown seems to match your existing set of defined points, (two values per point defined as: Condition, Value, Condition, Value,.....).  What pulse shape did you require?  Your original code does not show any MatLab integration formulation, for example:  int(f) .

Comment: How do you want it shaped?

Comment: @Nedd  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/64375/nedd  % clc 
% clear all
% a=2;
% b=1;
% c=3;x_t = @(t) t*(u(t-2)+u(t-3)-u(t-4));

subplot(2,2,1)

fplot(x_t,[0 5])

xlabel('time(sec)')

ylabel('magnitude')

title('x(t)') "this is my code trying to create it in terms of unit step because I don't know how to use ramp function" after testing the graph is right I will implement integration and derivation